# Stack concern : Local variables vs Arithmetics

Tags: c, performance, recursion, stack

I have a question regarding wether it is good to save arithmetics computations to limit the stack usage.

Let's say I have a recursive function like this one :

```
void foo (unsigned char x, unsigned char z) {
    if (!x || !z)
        return;
    // Do something
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        foo(x - 1, z);
        foo(x, z - 1);
    }
}
```

The main thing to see here are the `x - 1` and `z - 1` evaluated each time in the loop.
To increase performance, I would do something like this :

```
const unsigned char minus_x = x - 1;
const unsigned char minus_z = z - 1;
for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    foo(minus_x, z);
    foo(x, minus_z);
}
```

But doing this means that on each call, `minus_x` and `minus_z` are saved on the stack. The recursive function might be called thousand of times, which means thousand bytes used in the stack. Also, the maths involved aren't as simple as a `-1`.

Is this a good idea ?
**Edit : It is actually useless, since it is a pretty standard optimization for compilers : [Loop-invariant code motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)** (see HansPassant's comment)

Would it be a better idea to use a static array containing the computations like :

```
static const char minuses[256] = {/* 0 for x = 0; x - 1 for x = 1 to 255 */}
```

and then do :

```
foo(minuses[x], z);
foo(x, minuses[z]);
```

This approach limits a lot the actual maths needed but on each call, it has to get the cell in the array instead of reading it from a register.

I am trying to benchmark as much as I can to find the best solution, but if there is a best practice or something I am missing here, please let me know.

Comment: The operation `x - 1` creates a value on the stack anyway (even if you don't store it in a local variable).

Comment: @barakmanos Of course, but with the local variable, you have one push during the save of the local variables and one push when the the parameters of the next function call are copied. At least I think so.

Comment: You can simply try both options, run to depth 2 or 3, and check the value of the SP register.

Comment: @barakmanos Doing it right now.

Comment: Are you seeing an actual performance hit in this code? Modern compilers are smart enough to optimize these conditions automatically. You can compare the generated machine code if there is a real issue.

Comment: @metacubed That's hard to tell, since I need to compare time and the performance gain observed is around 1-2% so it could totally be because of external elements. Also, generated assembly is pretty hard to read to me. But I'm trying what barakmanos suggested me.

Comment: Invariant code hoisting is a standard optimization, pretty unlikely you have to help.  Of course you should profile it.  And stop when you find out it doesn't matter.

Comment: Did it myself. It indeed adds 24 bytes on each function call (using VS 2013). Seems that you are right!

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't know this optimisation feature name.

Comment: @barakmanos Does it return the same with optimisations active ?

Comment: @barakmanos Well, I just tried with `gcc`, and it seems like the stack pointer moves exactly the same way, even without optimizations.

Comment: Well then I guess VS 2013 doesn't use gcc :)

Comment: Ok, so I have my answer for question 1. But what about using a precomputed array ? Is this a good idea ?

Comment: @HansPassant In my case, the invariant code motion is inside an `if` : `if (something_which_changes_each_loop_iteration && constant_cond)`. Since this might never be evaluated, are you sure such an optimization still arises ? I know I could be sure it is applied by swapping the two conditions, but I want to understand a bit more how it works and my researches didn't give me an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I tried this with gcc, for two functions `foo_1()` (no extra variables) and `foo_2()` (extra variables).

With -03 gcc unrolled the for loop (!), the two functions were exactly the same size, but not quite the same code.  I regret I don't have time to work out how and why they differed.

With -02 gcc generated exactly the same code for `foo_1` and `foo_2`.  As one might expect it allocated a register to `x`, `z`, `x-1`, `z-1` and `i`, and pushed/popped those to preserve the parent's values -- using 6 x 8 (64-bit machine) bytes of stack for each call (including the return address).

You report 24 bytes of stack used... is that a 32-bit machine ?

With -O0, the picture was different, `foo_1` did the `x-1` and `z-1` each time round the loop, and in both cases the variables were held in memory.  `foo_1` was slightly shorter and I suspect that the subtraction makes no difference on a modern processor !  In this case, `foo_1` and `foo_2` used the same amount of stack.  This is because all the variables in `foo` are `unsigned char`, and the extra `minus_x` and `minus_z` pack together with the `i`, using space which is otherwise padding.  If you change `minus_x` and `minus_z` to `unsigned long long`, you get a difference.  Curiously, `foo_1` used 6 x 8 bytes of stack as well.  There were 16 unused bytes in the stack frame, so even taking into account aligning the RSP and the RBP to 16 byte boundaries, it appears to be using more than it needs to... I have no idea why.

I had a quick look at a static array of `x - 1`.  For -O0 it made no difference to the stack use (for the same reason as before).  For -O2, it took one look at `foo(x, minuses[z]);` and hoisted the `minuses[z]` out of the loop !  Which one ought to have expected... and the stack use stayed the same (at 6 x 8).

More generally, as noted elsewhere, any effective amount of optimisation is going to hoist calculations out of loops where it can.  The other thing which is going on is heavy use of registers to hold variables -- both real variables (those you have named) and "pseudo" variables (to hold the pre-calculated result of hoisted stuff).  Those registers need to be saved across calls of subroutines -- either by the caller or the callee.  The x86 push/pop operate on the entire register, so an unsigned char held in a register is going to need a full 8 or 4 (64-bit or 32-bit mode) bytes of stack.  But, hey, that's what you pay for the optimisation !

It's not entirely clear to me whether its the run-time or the stack-use which you are most concerned about.  Either way, the message is to leave it up to the compiler and worry if and only if the thing is too slow, and then only worry about the bits which profiling shows are a problem !

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to dig into it. I've made some high level optimisations during the last two weeks, and now I am digging in really low level concerns to boost it even more.
To answer your question, I have to consider both problems. The nature of the recursive algorithm involved (damereau-levenstein distance with a Trie) and the fact that it runs in a thread which stack size is 8M means stack size might be a problem. On the other side, the objective of this project is to have the fastest algorithm possible. Hence the difficulty and this kind of questions.

Comment: With your answer and the comment before, I will stick with my current version (which looks like the first I described), but will try to pack my variables to save space. I think it's the best solution here.

Comment: Well, if you are trying to squeeze the maximum out of your machine, you could consider replacing the recursion by an explicit stack... so you iterate down, pushing stuff as you go and popping stuff on the way back.  That way you have complete control over the space used, and you can take advantage of only needing a few bytes, compared to the 4 or 8 bytes per register pushed.  Mind you, you must be going pretty deep to run out of 8MB !

Comment: For some tree operations it's not even necessary to pop everything off when you are finished, the stack can simply be discarded.  For some things (eg. in-order traversal of a binary tree) an explicit stack can be used to keep track of where you are, so that a "next-node-please" function can be given the last known state of the traversal, which it updates.  The down-side is that you need to allocate the explicit stack... which means knowing the depth of the tree, or (for maximum simplicity) the maximum depth... how easy that is will depend on the tree in question.

Comment: Well, here the tree is guaranteed to be of a fixed size so it should be easy.